# Changing root path of swagger bundle javascript

Tags: flask, swagger, flask-restful

I'm having trouble in configuring the Swagger to my flask application which is deployed as a micro-service under another parent project.

As in the picture, the static files for Swagger are loaded like this
`<script src="/swaggerui/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>`

This is causing problem since the `.js` is attempted to resolve from the root path which is parent application that I don't control.

Where to specify Swagger to look for a custom path while loading those Javascript ? Simply adding a dot `.` in front should solve the issue

My code is like this

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api

app = Flask(__name__)
blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
api = Api(blueprint, doc='/doc/')
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was made possible by overriding `swagger_static` of the default template and passing necessary path via `spec_url` we can potentially change the path where swagger goes to look for the html & json.

The complete solution is as below

```
@apidoc.apidoc.add_app_template_global
def swagger_static(filename):
    return "./swaggerui/{0}".format(filename)

api = Api(app)

@api.documentation
def custom_ui():
    return render_template("swagger-ui.html", title=api.title, specs_url="./swagger.json")
```

Linking Github discussion https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/262#issuecomment-542490899